# Kernel panic : Kernel offset disabled

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, debugging, kernel-panic

I was trying to install the linux-next kernel in my system with the following steps.

1. Copied the existing configuration file from /boot to the root of source directory
2. Updated the .config file with `make oldconfig`
3. Compiled the modules with  `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers`
4. Installed the generated deb packages using `dpkg -i *.deb`.

When booting up the new kernel, it shows [image: Kernel panic message]
It shows up an error `Kernel Offset: disabled`. I'm unable to figure out the exact reason for this panic message. Let me know if I have to provide any other logs.

Answer (score -2):

While booting you will get two options
select the second one kali linux advanced settings
In the advanced settings choose recovery mode

you will boot into kali linux 
after a few seconds screen will ask for your root password
press control+D 
ready to go you will boot into ur os